# Lost 3G/4G signals, 2G works only; factory reset or downgrade or changes in network settings didn't help

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s-4, 3g, 4g, network-signal

I have a Samsung Galaxy S4 LTE working on Lollipop and I completely lost the 3G and 4G signals. I can only use the 2G signal.

- When I choose in the network options (Only HSPA) there's a stop like circle appearing instead of the signal scale up there.
- I tried the factory reset, but it didn't work.
- I also downgraded to Android 4.3  but the problem persisted.

What should I do?

Comment: you downgraded? Are you running a custom firmware or an aosp based rom? When did the problem occur?

Comment: Yes I tried various firmware versions but nothing helped. I think the problem happened when I was using 3G in a place where the signal was really bad so I switched to 2G only. Then when I got back home I tried to switch it back to the normal network settings and it received only 2G network. Knowing that when in the 2G/3G/4G mode the 2G is lost from time to time; "Emergency calls only" appears.